# Is it possible from qtwebkit get only moment interpretation html page?

Tags: c++, qt, webkit

It is necessary to make a multithreaded spider for sites to analyze web pages.

The problem with QtWebkit is that it is roughly based on widgets, and all widgets work only in the main thread.

Question:

1. Is it possible to bypass all this, to pull the moment of interpretation and construction of the document without rendering and return the feedback information ?
2. Maybe it's WebKit itself works ? Works in UI thread ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to explain a bit more what you are up to and what you have done so far. I am somewhat assuming that you try to collect data from web pages without displaying them. Why would you need WebKit for this at all? You could simply use a `QNetworkRequest`, set a user agent (important!), and send the request with `QNetworkAccessManager`. 
If you occasionally want to render data, pass a local copy to a WebBrowser instance.

If you need help on this path, consider reformulating you question appropriately.